# WordPress - Category page without category.php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, wordpress

I have a category for posts called test, which I wan't to display all posts in this category. Using this code:

```
$categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
      echo '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> '; } 
      ?>
```

so now, if I go to http://localhost:8888/category/test/ it displays all the posts of this category.

Now, my issue is that this page is not styled. I looked into the structure of wordpress, and found that if I made a category.php, this over writes the page before, but looses the functionality of displaying the selected categories posts.

Is there a way to locate this functionality?

Many thanks!

Comment: create empty category.php and put your code in it. have you tried it ?

Comment: I have, it over writes it all, but Im unsure how to then get the posts just from the selected category

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

duplicate the `category.php` page and rename it to `category-test.php`. Then you can use this to create a custom category template. https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: Issue is, There will be alot more than just this category, so I would need something where many categories could be added, and no code will be needed to be added

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that duplicating the index.php file, and renaming it to category.php works a treat, keeping the loop in from index.php was the issue

Answer (score 0):

if you have many categories and want to display your styling or the posts then add your custom code in `category.php`

for the current category You can use [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID; // this will give you current category id
```

pass your category id into the [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function

$posts_array = get_posts( array('category'=> $category_id ));

`$posts_array` will return you all the posts of current category